# Trying to parse a particular phrase between two specific strings in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to get a single word out of an unstructured text variable between two strings. An example would be from the text "Diagnosis based on BMD alone: Osteoporosis.", in which I would like to extract "Osteoporosis". Basically, I need to pull out the word between "alone:" and the period. I am using PRXPARSE but don't seem to have the syntax right; see below for my attempt.

```
data parse_data;
    set data;
    BY num;
    if _N_=1 then re = PRXPARSE("/\(alone: )(.*?)(\./)");
    if prxmatch(re, text) then new_text=prxposn(re, 1, text);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is invalid. Your delimiter, `/`, is inside the `)` when it should be outside.

Use the following regex instead. This uses a positive lookbehind `?<=` on `alone:` and a positive lookahead `?=` for `.` to capture the text in-between the two strings. `i` makes it case-insensitive, and `o` parses it only once.

`/(?<=alone:)(.*)(?=\.)/io`

A great testing suite for regex is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/O3tKbZ/1).

```
data parse_data;
    retain re;

    text = 'this is some text. alone: Osteoperosis.';

    if(_N_ = 1) then re = PRXPARSE("/(?<=alone:)(.*)(?=\.)/io");

    if(prxmatch(re, text) ) then new_text = strip(prxposn(re, 1, text) );

    drop re;
run;
```

Output:

```
text                                     new_text
this is some text. alone: Osteoperosis.  Osteoperosis
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error back: "Argument 1 to the function PRXMATCH must be a positive integer returned by PRXPARSE for a valid pattern"

Comment: Because of the `IF _N_=1` the variable RE must be retained.  Add `retain re;` to the data step.

Comment: Better - `re = PRXPARSE("/(?<=alone:)(.*)(?=\.)/o");` ("parse once" is the o argument).  I also like "i" (case insensitive) but only use that if you want Alone/alone/ALONE/etc. to all match.

Comment: Added Tom and Joe's recommendations

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone!!